# Take $-\log$ of a $\beta$ distributed R.V.

Tags: probability, statistics, transformation

$X_1,\dots,X_n \sim \beta(a,1)$, where $Y = -\log(X)$
Use the transformation formula to calculate the pdf of $Y$. What named distribution does it have?

I am confused what method to use here. A beta does not converge to a normal, so I cannot use the delta method?

Comment: -log implies -(natural log)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the transformation formula, the density for $Y$ should be 
$$
  f_Y(y) 
= e^yf_X(e^{-y})
= e^{-y}\frac{1}{B(a,1)}(e^{-y})^{a-1}  
= ae^{-ay}, \ \ \ 0 \leq y < \infty .
$$
This is an exponential distribution

Comment: No problem! Glad to have helped :)